# Using an image of data instead of the data when modeling

Tags: regression, time-series, classification, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

If we have many sequence data and corresponding plots, is there any reason we should use the image rather than the original data for deep learning?

Personally, I don't see any advantage of using CNN on the 2d image data since we could use a 1d CNN on the raw data.

Comment: @MichaelChernick I would guess this question came after he read after [this piece](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/reports/2015/pdfs/ashwin_final_paper.pdf).

Comment: Heh.  @displayname, if that paper is what you read, I believe it is meant to be taken in jest.

Comment: @MichaelChernick why?

Comment: @DiveIntoML I recently join an image recognition competition which uses plots as datasets. I think that's ridiculous, personally. And thanks for the paper.

Comment: Its ridiculous in practice yes, but for a competition, it may be just for fun.

Comment: Missed the first sentence.

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't any reason at all. By plotting the image you are only introducing noise.